# Where to store json file in ionic for ios?

Tags: ios, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I need to ship my application with a json file. The angular code then needs to read the json file and output the result into a view. I am very new to ionic and looked at the cordova-plugin-file plugin, but I am still not sure where to upload the file in my project. So the issue is that I don't know where to upload the file and how to read the same file. Any help or example code is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer in the following post:

http://www.raymondcamden.com/2014/07/15/Cordova-Sample-Reading-a-text-file